# AES Encryption in PowerShell and Python

Tags: python, powershell, cryptography, aes, pycrypto

My goal is to be able to AES encrypt a string in PowerShell, send it to a UNIX system with python available, and decrypt the string back to plain text. I would also like to be able to do the inverse. I am not a crypto guy or a PowerShell/python programmer, but this is what I have been able to do with the code so far:

```
function Create-AesManagedObject($key, $IV) {
    $aesManaged = New-Object "System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged"
    $aesManaged.Mode = [System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode]::CBC
    $aesManaged.Padding = [System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode]::Zeros
    $aesManaged.BlockSize = 128
    $aesManaged.KeySize = 256
    if ($IV) {
        if ($IV.getType().Name -eq "String") {
            $aesManaged.IV = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($IV)
        }
        else {
            $aesManaged.IV = $IV
        }
    }
    if ($key) {
        if ($key.getType().Name -eq "String") {
            $aesManaged.Key = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($key)
        }
        else {
            $aesManaged.Key = $key
        }
    }
    $aesManaged
}

function Encrypt-String($key, $unencryptedString) {
    $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($unencryptedString)
    $aesManaged = Create-AesManagedObject $key $IV
    $encryptor = $aesManaged.CreateEncryptor()
    $encryptedData = $encryptor.TransformFinalBlock($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length);
    [byte[]] $fullData = $aesManaged.IV + $encryptedData
    $aesManaged.Dispose()
    [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($fullData)
}

function Decrypt-String($key, $encryptedStringWithIV) {
    $bytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($encryptedStringWithIV)
    $IV = $bytes[0..15]
    $aesManaged = Create-AesManagedObject $key $IV
    $decryptor = $aesManaged.CreateDecryptor();
    $unencryptedData = $decryptor.TransformFinalBlock($bytes, 16, $bytes.Length - 16);
    $aesManaged.Dispose()
    [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($unencryptedData).Trim([char]0)
}

# key passphrase is a 16 byte string that is used to create the AES key.
$key_passphrase = "MypassphraseKey1"
# base64 encode the key.  The resulting key should be exactly 44 characters (43 characters with a single = of padding) (256 bits)
$Bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Ascii.GetBytes($key_passphrase)
$key =[Convert]::ToBase64String($Bytes)

# init is used to create the IV
$init = "This is an IV123"
# converts init to a byte array (e.g. T = 84, h = 104) and then sha1 hash it
$IV = (new-Object Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed).ComputeHash( [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($init) )[0..15] 
write-output "IV is equal to $IV"


write-output "AES key is $key"
$unencryptedString = "testing"
$encryptedString = Encrypt-String $key $unencryptedString
$backToPlainText = Decrypt-String $key $encryptedString

write-output "Unencrypted string: $unencryptedString"
write-output "Encrypted string: $encryptedString"
write-output "Unencrytped string: $backToPlainText"
```

The PowerShell script seems to be working fine for encrypting and decrypting. For the python side, I can define the same AES key value since it is just base64 encoded of my key's passphrase. However, I do not get the same encrypted value of the string when executing (e.g. PowerShell outputs UXKWIhtaUgFOvN13bvA4tx4+2Hjkv4v6I1G3Xfl6zp0= and Python outputs BOJ3Ox4fJxR+jFZ0CBQ25Q==). I believe these would need to match in order to be able to decrypt but I could be mistaken. I know setting a static IV and key makes it insecure, but I am willing to do that in order to be able to encrypt and decrypt across platforms (unless there is a better method using AES). Any help would be appreciated.

Python code

```
import base64, array
import Crypto
import Crypto.Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

def pad_data(data):
    if len(data) % 16 == 0:
        return data
    databytes = bytearray(data)
    padding_required = 15 - (len(databytes) % 16)
    databytes.extend(b'\x80')
    databytes.extend(b'\x00' * padding_required)
    return bytes(databytes)

def unpad_data(data):
    if not data:
        return data

    data = data.rstrip(b'\x00')
    if data[-1] == 128: # b'\x80'[0]:
        return data[:-1]
    else:
        return data

def encrypt(key, iv, data):
    aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    data = pad_data(data)
    return aes.encrypt(data)

def decrypt(key, iv, data):
    aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    data = aes.decrypt(data)
    return unpad_data(data)

def test_crypto ():
    key = "MypassphraseKey1"
    # found using the debugger in the PowerShell ISE to get the value byte value which was converted to hex
    iv = "\x51\x72\x96\x22\x1b\x5a\x52\x01\x4e\xbc\xdd\x77\x6e\xf0\x38\xb7"
    msg = b"testing"

    # hex value of IV in powershell script is 51 72 96 22 1b 5a 52 01 4e bc dd 77 6e f0 38 b7
    print("Value of IV: " + iv)

    # base64 encode key
    b64key = base64.b64encode(key)
    print("AES key encoded: " + b64key)

    code = encrypt(key, iv, msg)
    # convert encrypted string to base64
    b64encoded = base64.b64encode(code)
    print("Encrypted string: " + b64encoded)

    decoded = decrypt(key, iv, code)
    print("Decoded: " + decoded)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_crypto()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A couple suggestions:

1. A 16 character ASCII string is `128^16 = 5.19229686e33` possible key inputs. Base64-encoding 16 bytes yields 24 bytes (`4*ceil(16/3)`). So even though you are using a 192 bit AES key (theoretically `6.27710174e57` key combinations), you can use only `1/1208925820422879877545683` [one over one trillion trillion] of them. In fact, you set the key size to be 256 bits, and apparently the code is ignoring that/allowing the 192 bit key without an error.

Use [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes(v=vs.110).aspx) to derive your AES key rather than a Base64 transformation of a raw string. [RFC 2898](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898#page-9) defines PBKDF2 (Password-Based Key Derivation Function 2), an HMAC-based Key Derivation Function to securely derive encryption keys from passwords, and provides for HMAC/SHA1 used with a high number of iterations to mitigate brute-force attacks against your key.

1. You are only invoking `TransformFinalBlock()` on encrypt and decrypt in PowerShell. I imagine this will fail to encrypt or decrypt the complete message if the message is longer than one block (16 bytes). Try this with an input message like `This is a plaintext message.`  (29 bytes). I believe you want to use both [`TransformBlock()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.icryptotransform(v=vs.110).aspx) and `TransformFinalBlock()`.
2. You are correct that a static IV is unsafe (defeats the purpose of an IV, which should be unique and non-predictable for every encryption operation with the same key). `AesManaged` already provides a method [`GenerateIV()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.generateiv(v=vs.110).aspx) to generate a satisfactory IV, which you can access from the IV property and prepend to the cipher text.
3. Your PowerShell output of the Base64-encoded cipher text is 44 characters (`16 byte IV + 16 byte ciphered message = 32 bytes -> 44 bytes` in Base64). Your Python Base64 output is 24 characters (`16 bytes -> 24 bytes` in Base64). Either this output is not including the IV or the message (or some other less likely reason for the limited output). Looking at the code, your `encrypt` method does not prepend the IV onto the cipher text.
4. Finally, at this point, your code should work and be both internally consistent and cross-compatible. Here you should revisit a couple design decisions:

- Zero padding is non-standard and while you have implemented it manually, a well-defined padding scheme like `PKCS #5/#7` is more desirable. There are bountiful implementations and code examples for implementing this in both Python and .NET.
- You are using the [CBC block cipher mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation). While CBC is fine for confidentiality, it does not provide integrity. You should use an authenticated encryption mode (AE/AEAD) like GCM or EAX. If you cannot, provide a message authentication code (MAC) over the **cipher text** by using an HMAC construction like HMAC/SHA-256 with a **different** shared secret than your encryption key and verify the MAC **with a constant-time method** ***before*** attempting decryption.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the assistance. I have adjusted the python script based on some of your suggestions and removed the static IV. I know have the python script able to decode the powershell output and vice versa. I will work on implementing the other suggestions as well.

Comment: @MichaelWilliams I think that you should upvote the answer: if you accepted it, it probably means that it deserves a vote.

Comment: Sorry, new to stack overflow. I believe it should be upvoted now.

Comment: Thanks and no worries. Glad it was helpful.